# WHERE句で否定の論理和？

Tags: mysql

**対象のテーブル定義と内容**

```
CREATE TABLE r
    (`id` int, `age` int)
;

INSERT INTO r
    (`id`, `age`)
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 5),
    (4, 7),
    (5, 9)
;
```

**抽出したい結果**
「idが3ではない」または「ageが2ではない」レコード

1, 1
4, 7
5, 9

**試したSQL1**
意図しない結果になりました。
下記はどういう意味になるのですか？

```
 SELECT * FROM `r` WHERE  `id` != 3 OR `age` != 2;
```

**試したSQL2**
意図した結果を取得できたのですが、(ANDなのに)なぜですか？
これは否定の論理和ですか？？

```
SELECT * FROM `r` WHERE  `id` != 3 AND `age` != 2;
```

Comment: 所望の抽出結果を質問に書き加えていただけますか？

Comment: 抽出したい結果を追記しました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。その結果を見るに、添えるべき日本語は「"idが3ではない"かつ"ageが2ではない"レコード」だと思われます。

Answer (score 2):

SQL1は、否定論理和(NOR)でSQL2は否定論理積(NAND)です。

逆事象で考えるとわかりやすいかと思います。
SQL1は、id=3 AND age=2(A∩B)の逆事象なので、id!=3 OR age!=2（notA ∪ notB）となります。
意味でいうと(3,2)の組み合わせの逆事象なので、(3,2)の組み合わせ以外のものをSELECTしますとなります。

SQL2は、id=3 or age=2(A∪B)の逆事象なので、id!=3 AND age!=2（notA ∩ notB）となります。
id=3 or age=2でselectされる(2, 2)(3, 5)、これの逆事象なのでそれ以外が返ってきます。

また、A and BとA or Bのベン図を書いてみて、その逆のベン図を描いてみるのもわかりやすいかもしれません。